# Do I need to call MySQLdb.connect() in every method where I execute a database operation?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm new to using databases in Python and I'm playing around with MySQLdb. I have several methods that will issue database calls. Do I need to go through the database connection steps every time I want to make a call or is the instance of the database persistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection instance is persistent, you can connect one time and work with connection as long as you need.

Comment: Thank you! I hoped that was the answer.